# Bounding box with spritebatchnode

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

When i make a sprite batch node, the bounding box is empty. How do i get the bounding box or rect of a sprite batch node so I can use it for collision.

Comment: No idea why I am getting downvoted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SpriteBatch boundingBox is always empty. But as an alternative you can use bounding boxes of sprite batch children to check for collision

```
CCArray* children = _gameBatch.children;
NSUInteger childrenCount = children.count;
CCSprite* child;
for (NSUInteger pos = 0; pos < childrenCount; pos++) {
    child = [children objectAtIndex:pos];
    CGRect box = child.boundingBox;
}
```